Is there an easy way to convert an Indonesia string number into Chinese format in VB？
If I have a Chinese format number string like this "1.234".  it converts to "1,234"In Indonesia. My region setting is Indonesia ，how can I get the "1.234" in VB 6.0?
I hope there is an official function and an optional parameter that can solve my problem. Like str() or    Tostring()

Did you try CStr()? This takes care of the regional settings.

Whenever converting between string and a numeric type, you can specify the culture to use. Do so if you do not or may not want to use the current system culture. Take a look at the overloads available of the conversion methods, including ToString.

CStr() is only for integer

@jmcilhinney: VB6 doesn't have a ToString() method.

The way to do it is the Win32 API GetNumberFormat(Ex) and the help of a few other APIs like GetLocaleInfo, MAKELCID. See AllAPI.net for an example. And no, that's not easy. But the right thing(tm) is seldom the easy thing.

@HelO'Ween, I commented after getting here via the VB.NET tag, which was removed about the same time as I posted my comment. Using relevant and only relevant tags is important.
